# ROS Answers SE migration: fanuc m710 ic

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to know if it is possible to dialog with a fanuc m710 ic robot using ros ?

Are there any urdf files available ?

---

Edit: I agree, .... I have found some fanuc files for ros, however not for m710.

I also understood in lunar release , we should not use urdf files, but collada files ?
where to find these files ? provided by fanuc ?

I discovered ros industrial,  regarding fanuc dialog, fanuc_driver found (experimental release found) , not enough clear to novice like me what are karel tp...

---

Edit2: Ok, I have 3D models issued from fanuc. step or iges cad file.
however I think that is not  enough, this will not describe the robot kinematic .so urdf will come in action ? And I have to make it on my own ?

---

Edit3: I agree... my robotics collegue will do, and know karel tp... and fanuc robots...I am on software side ...I will not press the "run" button ;-)

I tried to generate an urdf file using xacro for m710ic50 , but it failed with find command :

```
rosrun xacro xacro --inorder  fanuc_m710ic_support/urdf/m710ic50.xacro

resource not found: fanuc_m710ic_support
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/lunar/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/lunar/share
XacroException('resource not found:',)
when processing file: fanuc_m710ic_support/urdf/m710ic50.xacro
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285297/fanuc-m710-ic/) by [sancelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34102/sancelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
What have you found yourself? We're here to help, but a quick google (`ros fanuc`) should show results relatively easily.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
Your `Edit3` is the last answer I'm merging into your question. Please **do not** post answers to ask more questions. Edit your original question using the `edit` button/link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have found some fanuc files for ros, however not for m710.

Basic support for M-710iC manipulators may be found at [fanuc_m710ic_support](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_m710ic_support). Xacros are only provided for the M-710iC/50 at the moment. You don't tell us which specific variant of the M-710 you have, so I cannot say whether we have xacros for it.

Note that the available drivers are manipulator agnostic, so they do not need to support any particular series or variant specifically to work.

> I also understood in lunar release , we should not use urdf files, but collada files ?

I'm not aware of this, so I cannot comment. If you can clarify where you have read this or who told you this I would be interested.

> I discovered ros industrial, regarding fanuc dialog, fanuc_driver found (experimental release found) , not enough clear to novice like me what are karel tp

This is a suggestion, but: if you haven't yet, *please* follow some basic Fanuc training *before* trying to use `fanuc_driver`, `fanuc_driver_exp` or any of the ROS-Industrial Fanuc packages with your robot. Karel and TP should be part of your basic knowledge when it comes to Fanuc robots, and both are needed.

These robots are dangerous and can be deadly, especially larger ones like the M-710.

We're here to help, but if ROS-Industrial is your first experience with Fanucs, then that may not be the best way to start.

---

Edit:

> Ok, I have 3D models issued from fanuc. step or iges cad file. however I think that is not enough, this will not describe the robot kinematic .so urdf will come in action ? And I have to make it on my own ?

please first take a look at `fanuc_m710ic_support` and see whether that contains files for your robot already. If not, creating a urdf/xacro is not that difficult.

---

Edit2:

> ```
> rosrun xacro xacro --inorder  fanuc_m710ic_support/urdf/m710ic50.xacro
> ```

> ```
> resource not found: fanuc_m710ic_support
> ```

Did you install the Fanuc packages before trying to run this command? If you did install them, how did you do that?

Note also: in order to test the xacro, just run (after installation):

```
roslaunch fanuc_m710ic_support test_m710ic50.launch
```

Refer to [Working with ROS-Industrial Robot Support Packages](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/WorkingWithRosIndustrialRobotSupportPackages) (also linked from the [fanuc_m710ic_support](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_m710ic_support) wiki page) for information on how to work with these packages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sancelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34102/sancelot/) on 2018-03-14**:
Finally, I created a catkin ws , I added industrial_core, fanuc, fanuc_experimental

launched catkin_make
and then being able to launch test_m710ic50.launch and show robot in rviz ....

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
Good to hear you got it to work.

Check the [Troubleshooting](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_driver/Troubleshooting) page if you have any other questions.